# How can I download file from s3 in php?

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-s3

How can I download file from s3 in php. The following code not working for me...
Here is my code

upload file should work correct

```
    try {
    $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => $config['s3']['bucket'],//'eliuserfiles',
        'Key'    => "uploads/{$name}",
        'Body'   =>  fopen($tmp_name, 'r+'),
        //'SourceFile' => $pathToFile,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ]);
```

download gives me error

```
  $objInfo = $s3->get_object_headers($config['s3']['bucket'], "uploads/{$name}");
    $obj = $s3->get_object($config['s3']['bucket'], "uploads/{$name}");

    header('Content-type: ' . $objInfo->header['_info']['content_type']);
    echo $obj->body;
```

error

```
 PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to Aws\\AwsClient::getCommand() must be of the type array, string given, called in /php_workspace/s3_php/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php on line 167 and defined in /php_workspace/s3_php/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php on line 211, referer: http://localhost/upload.php
```

Comment: This might be a version issue. Which version of aws are you using?

Comment: "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.8"

Answer (score 2):

**Simple way to do this:**

include `Amazon S3 PHP Class` in you're project.

instantiate the class:

**1. OO method (e,g; $s3->getObject(...)):**

`$s3 = new S3($awsAccessKey, $awsSecretKey);`

**2. Statically (e,g; S3::getObject(...)):**

`S3::setAuth($awsAccessKey, $awsSecretKey);`

**Then get Objects:**

```
// Return an entire object buffer:
    $object = S3::getObject($bucket, $uri));
    var_dump($object);
```

> Usually, the most efficient way to do this is to save the object to a file or resource

```
<?php

    // To save it to a file (unbuffered write stream):
    if (($object = S3::getObject($bucket, $uri, "/tmp/savefile.txt")) !== false) {
        print_r($object);
    }

    // To write it to a resource (unbuffered write stream):
    $fp = fopen("/tmp/savefile.txt", "wb");
    if (($object = S3::getObject($bucket, $uri, $fp)) !== false) {
        print_r($object);
    }

?>
```

[S3 Class -With Examples](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class)

[S3 Class -Documentation](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#getObject)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
$bucket= "bucket-name";
$filetodownload = "name-of-the-file";
$resultbool = $s3->doesObjectExist ($bucket, $filetodownload );
if ($resultbool) {
    $result = $client->getObject ( [ 
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $filetodownload 
] );
}
else
{
    echo "file not found";die;
}
header ( "Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}" );
header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filetodownload );
header ('Pragma: public');
echo $result ['Body'];
die ();
```